# Add additional fields to mysql

Tags: php, javascript

Hi I have some Javascript on my website which allows users to add additional fields to a form.  However I am not sure how to add these additional fields to the database.

my code is here, any suggestions on how to generate  this into a php variable would be appreciated.

```
 function addField(){
 var newContent = "<div class='item'><br><label for='qualification_title'>School   Qualification Title</label><input type='text' name='schoolqualificationtitle[]'/></div><div   class='item last'><br><label for='qualification_result'>Grade<em>*</em></label><input   type='text' id='result' name='schoolqualificationresult[]' />";
  $("#myfields").append(newContent);
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: with "field" you mean a database "column" or a database "row"?

Comment: If you're trying to add COLUMNS, look into the ALTER TABLE function for MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you post these additional fields the data will be passed to PHP in the array schoolqualificationtitle.

```
foreach($_POST['schoolqualificationtitle'] as $schoolqualificationtitle){
    // do some database shizzle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ONE user can have SEVERAL items. So this is a one-to-many relationship, meaning you need to add a row for each added item.